# Lemmatization of words using spacy and nltk not giving correct lemma

Tags: python-3.x, lemmatization

I want to get the lemmatized words of the words in list given below:

(eg)

```
words = ['Funnier','Funniest','mightiest','tighter']
```

When I do spacy,

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
words = ['Funnier','Funniest','mightiest','tighter','biggify']
doc = spacy.tokens.Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words)
for items in doc:
    print(items.lemma_)
```

I got the lemmas like:

```
Funnier
Funniest
mighty
tight
```

When I go for nltk WordNetLemmatizer

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() 
words = ['Funnier','Funniest','mightiest','tighter','biggify']
for token in words:
    print(token + ' --> ' +  lemmatizer.lemmatize(token))
```

I got:

```
Funnier : Funnier
Funniest : Funniest
mightiest : mightiest
tighter : tighter
```

Anyone help for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you also post your code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemmatisation is totally dependent on the part of speech tag that you are using while getting the lemma of the particular word.

```
# Define the sentence to be lemmatized
sentence = "The striped bats are hanging on their feet for best"

# Tokenize: Split the sentence into words
word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
print(word_list)
#> ['The', 'striped', 'bats', 'are', 'hanging', 'on', 'their', 'feet', 'for', 'best']

# Lemmatize list of words and join
lemmatized_output = ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in word_list])
print(lemmatized_output)
#> The striped bat are hanging on their foot for best
```

The above code is a simple example of how to use the wordnet lemmatizer on words and sentences.

Notice it didn’t do a good job. Because, ‘are’ is not converted to ‘be’ and ‘hanging’ is not converted to ‘hang’ as expected. This can be corrected if we provide the correct ‘part-of-speech’ tag (POS tag) as the second argument to lemmatize().

Sometimes, the same word can have a multiple lemmas based on the meaning / context.

```
print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("stripes", 'v'))  
#> strip

print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("stripes", 'n'))  
#> stripe
```

For the above example(), specify the corresponding pos tag:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() 
words = ['Funnier','Funniest','mightiest','tighter','biggify']
for token in words:
    print(token + ' --> ' +  lemmatizer.lemmatize(token, wordnet.ADJ_SAT))
```

Comment: Its not giving the lemmas for the word that included in the list specified in the problem definition.

Comment: In nltk, by default the pos tag in wordnetLemmatizer is set to Noun whereas the word "mightiest" is an adjective so you need to specify this while getting the lemma.

>>lemmatizer.lemmatize("mightiest", wordnet.ADJ_SAT)

Output : mighty

While in spacy, it internally passes the pos tag for corresponding word to lemma function.

Comment: yes, I tried that. But 'funnier' and 'funniest' is not giving the the lemma as 'funny'.

Comment: In [21]: lemmatizer.lemmatize("funniest", wordnet.ADJ_SAT)
Out[21]: 'funny'

Its giving the output when you pass the pos tag in wordnetlemma in nltk

Comment: Internally spacy uses the pre-defined/trained corpus for tagging the input. It might not contain funniest and funnier in its training corpus, thus tagging it to NOUN.

Comment: from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() 
words = ['Funnier','Funniest','mightiest','tighter']
for token in words:
    print(token + ' --> ' +lemmatizer.lemmatize(token, wordnet.ADJ_SAT))   gives [Funnier --> Funnier,
Funniest --> Funniest,
mightiest --> mighty,
tighter --> tight]

Comment: @Student I'm really happy the answer helped you. Please consider marking it as accepted, so that the others can rely on it.